# C++ Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minute(s), 2 second(s))

Tags: c++

After I execute the exe I get this error  :

Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minute(s), 2 second(s))

Should I set a limit to long variables ? I get 0 warnings after compiling

Here is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
//#define long long 100000000;
//#define int 1000;

using namespace std;
void test1();
void test2();
void test3();
int main()
{
    int p,n;
   // long z;
    long sir[2*n] ;
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open("input.txt");
    file >> p;
    file >>n;
    for (int i=0;i< (2*n);i++){
        file >> sir[i];
    }
    file.close();
    if (p==1)test1();
    else if(p==2)test2();
    else test3();
    return 0;
}
void test1(){
    cout << 1;//sir[2];
}
void test2(){
    cout << "d";
}
void test3(){
    cout << "d";
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't compile and if it does then it is definitely not standard. The size of an array must be known at compile time and `n` is not known nor is it initialized.

Comment: @MohamadElghawi gcc allows VLA's with the standard compilation flags.  I believe that is changing soon or already has in 6.0.

Comment: @MohamadElghawi Thanks dude ! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never initialized `n` before you used in `long sir[2*n] ;`.  This meas you use a garbage size do declare the array so now you have a garbage array.  Any use of that array is going to be undefined behavior and the cause of your problem.

Since `long sir[2*n] ;` is a variable length array and not standard I suggest you use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and set its size after you read it in from the file.  Something like the following should work

```
file.open("input.txt");
file >> p;
file >>n;
std::vector<long> sir(n);
```

If you can't use a vector then you can you a pointer and create the array with `new` after you read the size like

```
file.open("input.txt");
file >> p;
file >>n;
long * sir = new long[2*n];
```

You do have to remember to use `delete [] sir;` after you are done with it so you do get a memory leak.

Comment: Hi,I try to lean C++ by myself and I want to ask what advantages are using vectors? I saw in a place that vectors are arrays under the hood so aren't a big difference beetwen them

Comment: @CiolteAlin The advantage is the vector is self managing so you do not need to worry about cleanup.  It also has built in copying mechanisms and built in operators to make working with arrays easier.

Comment: Thanks and I have to solve problems with 3 requests,each problem has a long value, importing the vector class will make the final executable more bigger? The exe must be under 2 mb.

Comment: Also at this long * sir = new long n; it says that expect , or ; before n but this works long sir[2*n] ;

Comment: @CiolteAlin You need `long * sir = new long[2*n];`

Comment: Thanks and I have to solve problems with 3 requests,each problem has a long value, importing the vector class will make the final executable more bigger? The exe must be under 2 mb.

Comment: @CiolteAlin It should not.

Answer (score 0):

```
int p,n;
long sir[2*n] ; // here n is an undefined value, therefore the length of sir is undefined
```

Just put the definition of `sir` after `file >>n;`. Refer to `VLA` for more information.